# get background-image url from xpath

Tags: php, laravel, xpath

I tried following code and it returns `null`.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$doc->strictErrorChecking = false;
$doc->recover = true;

ini_set('user_agent', 'My-Application/2.5');
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc->loadHTMLFile('https://www.revolve.com/elliatt-cassini-dress/dp/ELLI-WD346/?d=Womens&srcType=hp_recs_viewed');
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$imgs = $xpath->query('//*[@class="zoomWindow "]');
foreach($imgs as $b){
    $datae[] = array(
        'img' => $xpath->evaluate(
            "substring-before(substring-after(./@style, \"background-image: url('\"), \"')\")",
        $b
        ),
    );
}
```

Here's the relevent `div` element,

```
<div style="z-index: 999; position: absolute; float: left; height: 536.406px; width: 355.141px; margin-top: 0px; margin-left: 0px; border: 0px solid rgb(136, 136, 136); background-position: -426.067px -499.099px; background-repeat: no-repeat; cursor: crosshair; overflow: hidden; background-image: url("https://is4.revolveassets.com/images/p4/n/z/ELLI-WD346_V1.jpg"); top: 0px; left: 0px; display: none;" class="zoomWindow">&nbsp;</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to scrape a website which is build with react.It probably won't be that easy. Pages rendered using React, or any other javascript framework, only load the majority of the content through javascript.Meaning initially the site load into the DOM then javascript adds new content to the DOM. If you want to scrape content from such websites you need to simulate and work within a headless browser. You could use PhantomJS for this.You can try some packages that usage phantomjs. but i suggest to use nodejs to use phantomjs or python.

Comment: thank you! I'm really new to web scraping and your advises helped me so much .From yesterday's answer I was able to scrape from multiple sites without problem. I'll look into this matter too. And there's one last website I'm having issues, Sorry for all these troubles. please take a look and tell me if there's any problem with that if you have a little bit of time. https://docs.google.com/document/d/1O6qoTxULTF7jdCk31W0u6CvfGyF43Tm2vTupEejRltY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @DevinY why don't you accept this answer?